# Replacing Flash movie with QuickTime movie in a website

Tags: javascript, html, flash, quicktime

Here is what I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.polycysticliverdisease.com/html/swfobject.js"></script> <div id="flashcontentab3445" align="center"> You probably do not have the Flash Player (<a href="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/">Get Adobe Flash Player Here</a>) installed for your browser or the video files are misplaced on your server!</div> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.polycysticliverdisease.com/html/easyflvsvab3445.js"></script>
```

Here is the .flv file: 
    polycysticliverdisease.com/html/debbie.flv

How do I replace it with a Quicktime movie?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Note that this is a repost of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647018/converting-flv-file-into-mov-file.

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript code doesn't say much, there's no reference to the swf file which I suppose is loading your flv file.

I guess you don't want to use Flash , otherwise why would you want to replace your flv with a Quicktime movie. You need to give more info about what you're trying to achieve otherwise the only answer you may get is just to link to the .mov version of your .flv

edit//

Google ".flv to .mov converter" and pick your choice. 
When you have a .mov file , you can create a link

```
 Click <a href=http://polycysticliverdisease.com/html/debbie.mov>here</a>to watch this movie!
```

and use the following code in the div of your choice , adapting the width & height values

```
 <EMBED SRC="debbie.mov" WIDTH=240 HEIGHT = 196 
  AUTOPLAY=true CONTROLLER=true LOOP=false 
  PLUGINSPAGE=http://www.apple.com/quicktime/">
```

Comment: Yes, I don't want to use Flash.

Comment: And I am absolutely unfamiliar with handling video, so I need a very detailed, "for dummies", directions. :)